# Extramarks, Fancyhdr and theorem environment numbering

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, theorems

I'm trying to do something as shown in the photos (bottom of the post). Note that I only want to edit the numbers, not the other text in the header. In other words, in even pages I want to have the most lower-level title number. For example, in Photo II we are in a section, so we show the section number, but we could also be in a subsection environment (if that were the case, then I would like to show the subsection number). And on the odd pages, I'd like to display **the number of the last theorem-defined environment in the page**. I think `\lastleftxmark` has to be edited somehow, and then do something with `\fancyhead[LE]{\thechapter}`.

Here's the code that we're interested on:

```
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancypagestyle{nor}{% <===========================================
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\lastrightxmark}}
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\lastleftxmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thechapter}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{+0.025\textwidth}
    \fancyheadoffset[RE,LO]{+0.0\textwidth}
}
\fancypagestyle{toc}{% <===========================================
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \fancyhead[RE,LO,RO,LE]{}
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textsc{Índex}}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[]{+0.025\textwidth}
}
% Pieter Van Oostrum - "In fancyhdr version 3, the initialisation was done when the first \pagestyle{fancy} (or one of its derived pagestyles) was given, including the initialisation of \chaptermark and \sectionmark"
\pagestyle{nor}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}\extramarks{}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\extramarks{\thesection}{#1}}

% Definicions, teoremes, lemes...
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposició}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corol·lari}
\newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Propietat}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definició}
\newtheorem{exmp}[theorem]{Exemple}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notació}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Observació}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Thanks in advance!

Mario

---

### Photo I

[image: I]

### Photo II

[image: II]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> II we are in a section, so we show the section number, but we could also be in a subsection environment (if that were the case, then I would like to show the subsection number).

This one is easy:

```
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\extramarks{\thesubsection}{#1}}
```

This also sets the subsection title for the header, by the way.

> And on the odd pages, I'd like to display the number of the last theorem-defined environment in the page.

This is more difficult. You would need an additional mark, independent from the others. I have a new implementation of the `extramarks` package, that can do this, but I haven't released it yet. If you want a prerelease, please send me an email, and I will give you the solution (I just tried it out at home).